# What is a good GUI tester?

Tags: java, user-interface, automated-tests

We need a tool to test a set of fairly complex Java applications. The applications are mostly independent client programs or applets communicating with a servlet or apache server at a remote site. Specs:

1. Runnable on Windows XP, Vista and 7
2. Parameterizable (Can specify in a script the sequence of buttons to click, text to type in JTextFields and browser address bar etc.)
3. Can quit or bail out or display a nasty message if the expected window or dialog box doesn't appear
4. Record the output on the Java Console of browser in a .txt file (IE is sufficient for now) when the application opens a browser window.
5. While running, I should be able to see it running with folded hands while it would run
   for a few minutes

We were thinking of writing an AWTRobot based tool that reads a command file and does this - (don't know how to do #3 or #4 yet - will ask you folks some day how to detect a window on the desktop). Would you suggest an open source tool available to do this? We don't need anything fancy to capture video or screenshots. Thank you, - M.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is an invitation for sales pitch, don't you think. How about Mercury Quicktest professional ( I believe its HP Quick test now). I do not believe this will be cheap either ( and well its HP, it will probably only work in IE ;)).

Since you want an open source solution, I believe, the most popular option is selenium and yes its a pain to configure sometimes ( like for Flex for example). So you should try [Watir](http://watir.com/).

There is a lot of good buzz around it and when I evaluated it, I loved what I see.Also it does not work for desktop applications, I suggest you try some other solution for that.

(The problem is open source GUI testing tools are not usually all inclusive. If you need one solution to handle all your gui testing needs, then  you should check out the more commercial ones like QTP.

Comment: Please checkout thoughtwork's Twist. It uses Sahi (http://sahi.co.in/w/) which offers a workable abstraction over selenium.

Answer (score 10):

For browser based automated testing you can use [Selenuim](http://seleniumhq.org/) or you can use WebDriver.
The selenium project is hosted [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/?redir=1)

Comment: Thanks for the links - Just browsed them - [from their page] In addition, the InternetExplorerDriver needs some additional components and can only be fully built on Windows 
Visual Studio 2008, with the 32 and 64 bit cross compilers for C++ and C# installed 
"msbuild" should both be on the PATH. This is most easily done by starting the "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt" from that Start menu ... We dont have Visual Studio and cannot test the stand-alone applications :(

Comment: The Visual Studio is needed only if you want to build InternetExplorerDriver from source code. You doesn't need to do it. There are prepared fully functional packages.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to test the way the pages are actually rendered by the browser, but instead need to work at the HTTP/HTTPS/etc request level then have a look at [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). It has parametrization, dataproviders, graphs, and a proxy component for recording http user sessions.

If you do need browser testing, then, as has already been mentioned, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is probably the best freely available tool. For production I would recommend using [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) server which can be driven by scripts written in Java/Python/C#/Perl/PHP.

To see what tools people use in real production environments, and to do your own research on what is available I recommend [www.sqaforums.com](http://www.sqaforums.com).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/)

The reason I suggest this is it sounds like you need to test both a Java applet and the content of a native browser (launched from Java, but not itself Java) -- so it's not "Java all the way".

I'm not sure what you mean by criteria 4, though.  It is worth noting that as Sukuli works by image analysis, it won't be able to copy text to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

I have used **IBM Rational Functional Tester**. It has everything you need and it's quite easy to learn. The scripting language is either Java or VB.Net so you won't have to worry about learning a language for your tests.

Comment: I am sure it's a good tool - but they are asking $11,000+ for 1 (one) floating license for a year. That is way beyond our budget. Thanks for the information, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had some pretty good results with Squish from FrogLogic and didn't break the bank: http://www.froglogic.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Squsih - http://www.froglogic.com/products/index.php